# What are these tiny kidney bean sized things in my rotisserie chicken

Tags: chicken

I was trying to separate the bone and chicken meat to make soup when all of a sudden I see these tiny kidney bean things.literally the same size and everything but it was inside the chicken. Which is a rotisserie style chicken from the store. What are they. I cut into them no weird stuff and im sure they are too small to be the chickens actual kidney. This chicken was way too big[image]

Comment: As an aside: this meat has not been cooked through - note the red or glassy looking parts. All the meat should be white; eating this may cause a serious stommach infection.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Incorrect. Color is not a good indicator of doneness, especially for dark meat and near the bone. Several things can cause this, including the presence of non-denatured myoglobin, naturally occurring nitrites, reaction of hemoglobin with heated gases, etc. (https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/poultry-preparation/is-pink-turkey-meat-safe_/ct_index)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n I will also note the presence of gelatin (upper left) indicates that if anything, this chicken was possibly *overcooked*, as collagen melts faster at higher temperatures.

Comment: Granted I clicked on this question after reading the title ...a part of me wishes the picture was put in a "spoiler" tag so I had to click it...

Answer (score 61):

Your chicken was a rooster and what you found are his testicles. If you are not queasy, [this forum entry](https://www.backyardchickens.com/threads/chicken-testicles-warning-pictures-of-raw-meat.163816/page-6) gives you a picture and some more anatomical details.

While animal testicles are typically [edible](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testicles_as_food) and often a speciality/delicacy, many westerners are not necessarily familiar with them, especially in animals as comparatively small as roosters. Asian (e.g. Chinese) cuisine knows various dishes based on chicken testicles, and there‘s also a [Hungarian dish](https://tastehungary.com/journal/kakashere-porkolt-rooster-testicle-stew/) that’s basically a stew/goulash.

On the other hand, they have [confused unwitting consumers](https://metro.co.uk/2018/03/02/girl-14-finds-testicles-inside-asda-roast-chicken-eating-7354516/amp/) as readily reported by the kind of media that favors sensationalism.

So don’t worry, you can simply eat them, if you want. Or get inspired by Heston Blumenthal’s [Regency recipe](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mZCkW23Y8hQ) for his [Fairytale Feast.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mR4N2-AakrA&list=PLgv4Fw_iuz1Gm1wJfsJJIUkJkkaP-cO5g&index=6)

Comment: Thank you lol...and hey I am Hungarian sOoooooo..but I really appreciate your answer because my worst fear of eating a parasite was not fun.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, +1 :)

Comment: In the US at least, those are normally not seen but given that most commercial chickens are only 6-8 weeks old and not mature, they are fairly small and sometimes missed.

Comment: From the Metro article: _"we completely accept that we dropped a ball here"_ hehe

Answer (score 2):

Those are testicles. Your chicken was not a rooster (as another answer declares), it was a cockerel -- and immature rooster. If it had been a rooster those testicles would have been quite large.